# sinhala character recognition to Flutter application

Tags: flutter, ocr

How to integrate sinhala character recognition to Flutter application.
I want to convert image file to sinhala word file
I tried various way for do this.(Google's ML Kit for Flutter) but i cant reach to proper converting sinhala characters.
Please can you any help for this...

Comment: Can you add an image(which we need to convert) in your question? And if we are able to convert that image into sinhala then it should be shown as "Text" or what?